# Sharing configuration across modules in Springboot multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp

I am setting up a new multi-module Springboot project.

**MyApp(root)**

- **my-app-commons**
- **my-app-api-a**

The **my-app-commons** module will have the model classes and so Application(Main) class isn't required and it can be used as a library (dependency) in other modules.

I intend to connect to GCP bucket from the **my-app-api-a** module.In future I will have to add more child modules to MyApp. I was thinking if I can have my GCP storage related configuration inside the **my-app-commons** module and use it as spring managed dependency (autowired) in **my-app-api-a** module, and possibly in future modules, instead of repeating the configuration related code in multiple modules.

As I am a beginner, I am not sure if its a good approach. I also think I will need Application(Main) class and have component scan to read the configuration.

Please can you suggest the best practice for what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: Do you want to share the commons module with different app and have it stored centrally to be able to import it easily?

Comment: Publish your module in Artifact Registry. You have a maven repository managed for you. It's the best place. https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/store-java